# How can I do the "cleanup" badge task?

Tags: support, badges

How can I do the cleanup badge task? I can't find any information about how to do it anywhere, I would be grateful if you can help me.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "clean up task"? Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: @JohnConde I added the visual of which achievement is in the question. I don't know how to make the achievement in the visual I added. Can you give information about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the badge description, and [this Main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/236563) state - Complete your first Rollback.

A rollback is the reversion of an edit.
Click on the edit history of a post - where it says *edited x hours ago*.
This gives all the edits performed on the post
Click on the word *Rollback* on the state of the post you wish to restore.

If you have edit rights, the rollback occurs immediately.  Otherwise it goes into the *Suggested Edits* review queue like any other proposed edit and your rollback only takes place if approved.